# How to make vuejs respond faster when using v-model on large data sets

Tags: performance, vuejs2, vue.js

The application i'm working on renders an array of persons and their children. There are about 600 persons in the array. I am displaying the person name and the names of each person's children in text inputs so that they can be edited. I use a `V-model` for two way binding so I can easily save the edits.

```
<tr v-for="person in persons">
  <td>
    <input type="text" v-model="person.name" />
  </td>
  <td v-for="child in person.children">
    <input type="text" v-model="child.name" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is when I start typing in the textboxes, there is a lag and I have to wait some seconds before what I typed displays.

This doesn't happen when I use `v-bind:value` or when I reduce the number of persons coming from the api  to say 50 persons. I could use pagination but my boss wants to see all the results displayed at once.

My question is, how can I make `vue.js` perform faster while using two way binding on large data?.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you can try to use v-bind:value and an onKeyDown listener to update the value.

Comment: why you do not paginate it?

Comment: Use `v-model.lazy="property.name"` But yes this a bit too much data, so better integrate some kind of pagination.

Comment: Thanks @BelminBedak . v-model.lazy worked like a charm.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it as answer with a bit detailed explanation.

Comment: that amount of data should not be a problem, usually. Can you provide a reproduction on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you are dealing with bunch of data It's always good idea to integrate the sort of pagination, but sometimes It's just not an option.

There is modifier called `.lazy` that lives on `v-model` directive.What it does is sync input with data model after change event.

Usage is pretty simple:

```
<input v-model.lazy="msg" >
```

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy

Comment: I still find very odd that vuejs has problems dealing with 600 v-models without this option on. Once I've created a view with angular 1 with 3000 ng-models and I had no problem at all.

Comment: well, it shouldn't, usually. Btu it might be a good idea to use a `key` attribute

Comment: @tocqueville check this example - 500 items here http://jsbin.com/fidifacote/edit?html,js,output works normally without lazy modifier.

Comment: @BelminBedak  your example works as well with 1700 items without lag for me

Answer (score 15):

I have had a similar issue, and using v-model.lazy did not solve it. It performed a little bit better, but not as much as doing it manually.

So instead of:

```
<input v-model.lazy="msg">
```

I used:

```
<input :value="msg" @change="v => msg = v">
```

In theory it's pretty much the same, but in practice I found it much faster (at least using it on a `<b-form-input>` in Bootstrap-vue)

Comment: v-model listens for `@input`. If you listen for `@change` then you're doing a lot less work than v-model.

Comment: Thanks. `v-model.lazy` wasn't working for me either. This is.

Comment: Not work for me, onchange put [object Event] in my var.

Answer (score 1):

In reponse to Tarrakis, v-model.lazy isn't workign for you because you are using it on a custom component (a bootstrap form input component) and v-model.lazy doesn't work for custom components.